# Rounding Issue With Python

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

This code

```
np.uint32( 1.13*100 )
```

returns 112

It should be 113.

How can I get around the strange rounding issue and make it return 113?

I am on numpy 1.9.1

Comment: start with `1.13*100` you'll see it is not `1.12`. (there has to be a question here that explains what is wrong with floats, but I can't find it for now)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) There it is.

Comment: `np.uint32` truncates. Try `np.uint32(1.99)`

Answer (score 4):

If you can avoid it, don't cast the result of a floating point multiplication directly to an integer. Casting doesn't round the number to the nearest integer, it merely drops the decimal part of the float.

The problem is that floating point numbers are often only close approximations of real numbers. Arithmetical operations can exacerbate discrepancies. In your example:

```
>>> 1.13*100
112.99999999999999
```

The decimal part is dropped upon casting to an integer, leaving `112`.

It would be better to round the number to the nearest integer first (e.g. with `np.round`) and then cast it to an integer type:

```
>>> np.int32(np.round(1.13*100))
113
```